# How to Opt-out Android Auto from google play console

Tags: android, android-auto

I can't opt-out Android auto support from the google play console Advanced settings -> release type (Classic console - Pricing & distribution ), even though I have removed all the entries from manifest/merged manifest which are related to android auto. Because of this my app keep getting rejected and this is the message I got from google

**App category not permitted**
At this time, we are only accepting apps within the Media, short form Messaging, or categories supported by the Android for Cars App Library. Media apps that use TSS engine readout for content are not permitted at this time.

[Google play console release type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UWaM.png)

Answer (score 3):

1.Review the checklist to prepare your APK.
2.Sign in to your Play Console.
3.Select the app with the policy violation.
4.On the left menu, select Release management > App releases.
5.Next to the release type you want to create, select Manage.
6.To create a new release, select Create release.
7.Follow the on-screen instructions to upload the modified, policy compliant APK **across all tracks**, and deactivate the non-compliant APK(s).
To deactivate a non-compliant APK, please upload a compliant APK to the same track.
Be sure to increment the APK version number and **set the release to 100% rollout**, in order to successfully override and deactivate the non-compliant APK.
Submit your app

Comment: I had a previous release in a different track that still contained reference to Android Auto. After I removed that and re-uploaded a new release, then the opt-out took effect.